# Visual Studio 2010 locking referenced Assembly

Tags: visual-studio-2010

I have a sandbox app that is built from the simple WPF Application template.  This sandbox references an assembly that I am also building which contains the definition of a UserControl (WPF).  I am instantiating this user control in the sandbox, to test the control's behaviour.  The point of all this is to speed up development.

This worked fine, but recently the .Vshost.exe paired with the sandbox process won't shut down.  This prevents me from recompiling the Controls library, though ironically I *can* recompile the sandbox application.  I can't kill the vshost process with Task Manager... only restarting VS2010 will clear it out.  But every time I run the application from VS, the process just hangs there, blocking my workflow.  I'm at a loss.

Any ideas what could be causing this?  Or does someone have any proposed workaround (mega-kill switch, perhaps?)

Comment: Does your application close cleanly? `yourapp.vshost.exe` might be kicking around because your application hasn't closed properly.

Comment: I just ran it under debugger, with full exception handling on.  Next exceptions thrown, and this is the output:

The thread 'vshost.RunParkingWindow' (0x1020) has exited with code 0 (0x0).
The thread '<No Name>' (0x223c) has exited with code 0 (0x0).
The program '[8272] PrototypeSandbox.vshost.exe: Program Trace' has exited with code 0 (0x0).
The program '[8272] PrototypeSandbox.vshost.exe: Managed (v4.0.30319)' has exited with code 0 (0x0).

But the process PrototypeSandbox.vshost is still in the task list.

Comment: Microsoft suggests turning off `vshost` - http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/358562/application-vshost-exe-does-not-close-properly

Comment: @todda.speot.is Excellent suggestion, that seems to work.

Answer (score 1):

[Similar StackOverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3736324/vs2010-doesnt-always-release-dlls-before-building)

The answer to the StackOverflow question led me to this set of tools:

[VSCommand](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/d491911d-97f3-4cf6-87b0-6a2882120acf/)  There is an Apply Fix command that allows you to close down any parent process (in this case, it may end up closing VS itself).

Todda.speot.is's response worked well: [Microsoft suggests turning off vshost](http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/358562/application-vshost-exe-does-not-close-properly)

Comment: Glad I could help.